# cancan gem simple question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

## models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
      can :create, Comment
      can :update, Comment do |comment|
        comment.try(:user) == user || user.role?(:moderator)
      end
      if user.role?(:author)
        can :create, Article
        can :update, Article do |article|
          article.try(:user) == user
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In Railscasts there are  methods user.role? :admin & if user.role?(:author).I dont get it. Do i need to create a method in model to make it work?

I'm storing roles in Users table as a role column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to write this yourself. However, the CanCan project has a [wiki page describing how to do this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/role-based-authorization).

The first line of the wiki says:

> "CanCan is decoupled from how you
>   implement roles in the User model, but
>   how might one set up basic role-based
>   authorization?"

Note that I disagree almost completely with the example on that page that uses a `role_mask`, but the page is still good and should give you some ideas.

There is also the [Separate Role Model example](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model), which I personally like better. It depends on where you want to store your role information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a gem that is plug-and-play, then check out Declarative Authorization.
Raynb says that he developed Cancan because DA was overkill for some projects here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?autoplay=true